# "Does your app contain, display, or access third-party content?"

Tags: ios, app-store, submission

-while submitting app apple ask this question ##Does your app contain, display, or access third-party content?##.i clicked on yes Option by mistake 
-now how can i edit that 
-i want make it No
-how to edit again
-Help me out

-thanks

Comment: login in your `itunes account` and just change it for your app!

Comment: You will need to reject the build and resubmit

Comment: @Paulw11 while resubmit it wont show again

Comment: Any luck with this? I am also stuck at this point